# stream tweets with kafka in python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, tweepy

i am trying to streaming tweets for my project with kafka but a got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bigdata/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 441, in __del__
    self._close()
  File "/home/bigdata/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 415, in _close
    if not self._closed:
AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute '_closed'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/bigdata/pythonscripts/testKafkaStreaming.py", line 28, in <module>
    kafka = KafkaClient("localhost:9092")

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

help me please what can i do

Comment: have you got any solution, because I am facing the same error

Comment: unfortunately no, i changed my project architecture, i find that its preferable to use kafka with java language